# move all files except one that matches filename

Tags: find, mv

I want to move all files in my current directory to a directory named `NewDir` that end with `*.bam`, except for a specific file named `special.file.bam`.

I have found this command that *removes* all files, but not sure how to *move* them, not deleting them:

```
find . ! -name 'special.file.bam' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your shell is the bash shell, you can simply do as following by enabling the Extended Glob:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv -- !(special.file).bam temp/
```

to suppress the error:"*`bash: /usr/bin/mv: Argument list too long`*" when there are too many files matching the given pattern, do as following:

```
for file in !(special.file).bam; do
    mv -- "$file" temp/
done
```

---

**or with the `find` command instead and portability:**

```
find . -path './*' -prune -type f -name '*.bam' ! -name 'special.file.bam' \
    -exec sh -c 'for file; do mv "$file" temp/; done' sh_mv {} +
```

remove `-path './*' -prune` part to find files in sub-directories too.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of files exceeds the command-line length, you still need to use `find`. I would suggest to combine it with `xargs` and null delimited files (`\0`), e.g.:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.bam' ! -name 'special.file.bam' -print0 |
xargs -0 mv -t /path/to/destination
```

Note: not exhaustively tested, use with care.

Answer (score 2):

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.bam" ! -name "special.file.bam" -exec mv {} NewDir \;
```

Comment: always use slash at the end of the second argument, like `mv {} NewDir/` so in case `NewDir` directory was not exist your files all will not be overwrite on single file `NewDir`, instead mv will complain `cannot move ...... 'NewDir/': Not a directory`

Answer (score 0):

```
mv -f $(find ./*.bam -maxdepth 1 ! -name "special.file.bam" -type f) NewDir/
```

Comment: this will fail on files name having whitespaces or newline characters

Comment: It would also fail with "argument list too long" if there are a lot of names matching `*.bam` in the current directory.

Comment: ok, thanks. But it worked in my instance. downrate is probably not needed.

Comment: All you need to do to fix your one-liner (provided too many files are not an issue) is:  `mv -f -- "$(find ./*.bam -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name 'special.file.bam')" NewDir/` Note the quoting... it should take care of special filenames with `\n`and spaces in them or of files starting with hyphen(s). This said, αғsнιη 's answer is the more portable one.